# New to r, grabbing a column value when knowing another

Tags: r

I know a value, for example "purchase amount" for $682.23, how would I print a value from the column "Date"
table examples...

```
{DATE} {Purchase amount} {ITEMS}
2018        682.23        cheese 
2017        752.25        cheese
```

so for this even though I know its 2018 what form of code would I use to grab that value without grabbing "cheese" as well. I have tried a few things already to no avail.
P.S. very new to coding so I'm reaching out for help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored in a data.frame `df`

```
df$Date[df$`Purchase amount` == 682.23]
```

Comment: That worked amazingly, thank you so much for the help! very new to coding so things like this are completely foreign to me.

Comment: Please mark as the "accepted" answer.  Thank you!